# send contact form fields within an email

Tags: php

I am a .net developer, I have to do some simple work for a client in php.

I have one html page with 4 forms (one submit button for each form).

I'll show You the code for 1 form (I have 4 forms exactly the same):

html:

```
 <form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="sendmail.php">

    <div class="af-textWrap">
        <input id="fullName" type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="fullName" class="text" value="" tabindex="500" required />
    </div>

    <div class="af-textWrap">
        <input class="text" placeholder="Your email" id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" required />
    </div>

    <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
        <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="" tabindex="503" />

    </div>

</form>
```

php:

```
<?php

  $EmailTo = "xxx@gmail.com";
  $Subject = "Details left";
  $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fullName'])); 
  $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 

  $Body = "";
  $Body .= "Name: ";
  $Body .= $Name;
  $Body .= "\n";
  $Body .= "Email: ";
  $Body .= $Email;
  $Body .= "\n";

  $headers  = 'From: xxxx@contact.com' . "\r\n" .
          'Reply-To: xxxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
          'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
          'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  if(mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers))   
    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: secondPage.html");
    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */

  else
      echo "Email sending failed"; 
  ?>
```

The mail is arriving OK.
The fields (name and email) text, don't.
What is wrong here?

```
$_POST['fullName'])
```

fullName- is the id or the name?

what I want to achieve-
for every form (4 forms, 4 submit buttons)
suppose I am filling the 3'rd form and hitting the 3'rd form button
an email will be send, containing name and email text from the 3'rd form fields (not from other forms)

- hope I have explained it ok

Comment: *"what I want to achieve- for every form (4 forms, 4 submit buttons) suppose I am filling the 3'rd form"* - Ok, so show us the code for the other forms. What you posted worked fine for me.

Comment: What I think is happening is that none of your submit buttons have name attributes in all your **4 forms**, and is defaulting to the first executed submit in another form not containing the POST variables. Name your submit buttons and use `isset()` in conjunction with which form you wish to execute. Other than that, you really need to post your full code. Nobody will ever be able to give you a definite answer.

Comment: @Fred , You right- non of my submit buttons have name attributes in all your 4 forms.
can You pleas explain what to do? and why is it matter?

Comment: I believe that I already have explained it.